# Usage of PATH in Python's subprocess module

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I've stumbled upon a strange behaviour with Python's [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module:

```
>>> import os, subprocess
>>> del os.environ["PATH"]
>>> subprocess.run(["python", "--version"])
Python 3.5.1
CompletedProcess(args=['python', '--version'], returncode=0)
```

I wonder how the command is run with the `PATH` environment variable unset? Is there any default `PATH`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a default PATH, at least in Linux.

Consider this quote from the [Linux execl() man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl):

> If [the PATH variable] isn't defined, the path list defaults to the current directory followed by the list of directories returned by confstr(_CS_PATH). (This confstr(3) call typically returns the value "/bin:/usr/bin".)

Answer (score 0):

There is [`os.defpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.defpath):

> The default search path used by `exec*p*` and `spawn*p*` if the
>   environment doesn’t have a `'PATH'` key. Also available via `os.path`.

It is hardcoded to `':/bin:/usr/bin'` in [`posixpath.py` (`os.path` on POSIX systems)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ce60ae99d349762c15383684c3a7f42667806cf3/Lib/posixpath.py#L35) and `'.;C:\\bin'` in [`ntpath.py` (`os.path` on Windows)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ce60ae99d349762c15383684c3a7f42667806cf3/Lib/ntpath.py#L30).